# problems that Connected to multiple drivers or bad synchronous description

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I just want to make my point (SQ_X2,SQ_Y2) move in 2D plane(in TFT-LCD).
following is part of my code.

If I Push PSW(Push button switch), and point moves 5 in x or y. and there is problem, when I merge following code in one process statement, there is an error "that bad synchronous description".
but to avoid this problem, I declare 4 Process statements, there is another error that Signal SQ_X2 or SQ_Y2 is connected Multiple drivers.
I am in now dilemma.. plz help me and I will buy a pizza

```
PROCESS (PSW(3))
BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(PSW(3))) then
        SQ_Y2 <= SQ_Y2 - std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(5,10));
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS (PSW(2))
BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(PSW(2))) then
        SQ_Y2 <= SQ_Y2 + std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(5,10));
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS (PSW(1))
BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(PSW(1))) then
        SQ_X2 <= SQ_X2 - std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(5,10));
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS (PSW(0))
BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(PSW(0))) then
        SQ_X2 <= SQ_X2 + std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(5,10));
    END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

Comment: Where's the clock signal? Look up synchronous design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign one signal in multiple processes(more accurately, there are ways you could do that, but you don't want to do it here). Also, one process can only contain one `if rising_edge() then` statement, because it's not possible to synthesize hardware that reacts to multiple rising edges...

What you need to do is learn about synchronous design, add a clock to your system and do it all in one process. You might want to take a look at [this tutorial](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/tutorial/), especially the sequential logic design section.